# Myscript not working in my localhost but if in jsfiddle it's fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, localhost

i don't know what wrong with my code. if my script running in jsfiddle it's fine. but if in my computer(localhost) it's not working.

Here's my jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fma1hyoL/5/)

Here's my script i running in my computer

```
<html>
<body>
<input id="nominal" type="text" />
<script>
$(function() {
    var money = 20000;

    $("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
        var input = $(this);

        // remove possible existing message
        if( input.next().is("form") )
            input.next().remove();

        // show message
        if( input.val() > money )
            input.after("<form method=\"post\" action=\"\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"yes\" value=\"Yes\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"no\" value=\"No\"></form>");
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to include jquery to your file

Comment: Is jQuery included in localhost?

Comment: what jquery i must include? @scrappedcola

Comment: @Eightleven Use the latest one: http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery library to use jQuery functions:

Put this above you script tags:

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.slim.js"   integrity="sha256-L6ppAjL6jgtRmfiuigeEE5AwNI2pH/X9IBbPyanJeZw="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    var money = 20000;

    $("#nominal").on("change keyup", function() {
        var input = $(this);

        // remove possible existing message
        if( input.next().is("form") )
            input.next().remove();

        // show message
        if( input.val() > money )
            input.after("<form method=\"post\" action=\"\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"yes\" value=\"Yes\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"no\" value=\"No\"></form>");
    });
});
</script>
```

It will load jQuery from a CDN into your page.